# How do I use Java-8's flatMap operation for certain cases?

Tags: java-8, option-type

I am using Java-8 's `flatMap` operation to make a part of my code smaller.

I know that if my code is as follows:

```
if (giftOptional.isPresent()) {
    Gift gift = giftOptional.get();
    Optional<Boolean> giftIsWrapped = gift.isWrapped();
    return giftIsWrapped.isPresent() && giftIsWrapped.get();
}
return false;
```

then it can be changed to:

```
return giftOptional.flatMap(Gift::isWrapped)
                   .orElse(Boolean.FALSE);
```

but what if the `isWrapped` method does not return an `Optional`? That is, if the code is like this:

```
if (giftOptional.isPresent()) {
    Gift gift = giftOptional.get();
    boolean giftIsWrapped = gift.isWrapped();
    return giftIsWrapped;
}
return false;
```

then can the same code apply? That is:

```
return giftOptional.flatMap(Gift::isWrapped)
                   .orElse(Boolean.FALSE);
```

Also, what if I need to add some argument to the function? For example, the code is:

```
if (giftOptional.isPresent()) {
    String gift = giftOptional.get();
    boolean giftIsWrapped = gift.equals("some string");
    return giftIsWrapped;
}
return false;
```

what should be the corresponding code using `flatMap` in that case?

Answer (score 3):

You needed to use `flatMap` to unwrap or "flatten" the nested `Optional`.  If `isWrapped` returns a `boolean`, simply use `map` instead of `flatMap`:

```
giftOptional.map(Gift::isWrapped).orElse(false);
```

You can always use a lambda expression inside `map` to express the mapping logic.  In your case, you can use `.map(gift -> gift.equals("some string"))`.  That happens to be the same as `"some string"::equals`, but you cannot always reduce a lambda into a method reference.

The code above will work with any return type.  However, since in your case you are dealing with a `boolean`, you can use `filter` instead of `map`:

```
giftOptional.filter(Gift::isWrapped).isPresent();
```

Comment: Ah, got it, thanks. Can you please also tell me what do I do when I need to add an argument to the function? You can check the last part of my question if you want to look at an example code for reference.

Answer (score 2):

You want [`filter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-):

```
return giftOptional.filter(Gift::isWrapped).orElse(Boolean.FALSE);
```

`filter()` takes a [`Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html), which can be a method reference, and works as you would expect and as you want in your case.

---

You can still use `filter()` with a method reference for comparison with a `String`:

```
return giftOptional.filter("some string"::equals).orElse(Boolean.FALSE);
```

Comment: Got it, thanks. Would you also happen to know what should be the code if the function required an argument to be passed to it, as mentioned in the final part of my question?

Comment: @SanjibanBairagya see edited answer for alternate code

Comment: I'm afraid the solutions mentioned here are not compiling. I'm getting the following errors respectively:

`error: incompatible types: Boolean cannot be converted to Gift`,
and,
`error: incompatible types: Boolean cannot be converted to String`

Comment: @SanjibanBairagya what code exactly is giving the error(s)?

Comment: `private boolean f1(Optional<Gift> giftOptional) {
        return giftOptional.filter(Gift::isWrapped).orElse(Boolean.FALSE);
    }`,
and,

    `private boolean f2(String s) {
        return s.filter("some string"::equals).orElse(Boolean.FALSE);
    }`

Comment: Replacing `filter` with `map` is making the code to compile though. Should `return s.map("some string"::equals).orElse(Boolean.FALSE);` do the same operation as was intended by `return s.filter("some string"::equals).orElse(Boolean.FALSE);`?

Comment: @SanjibanBairagya because `Predicate<T>` is a `Function<T, Boolean>`, in this case `map()` and `filter()` are effectively the same thing. You should use whatever makes the code clearer,